# how do I call <breed>-here procedure when <breed> is to be passed as an argument or a parameter within a function in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

How do I get to specify the breed name for `<breed>-here`  when this is passed as a parameter to another function? I get a syntax error currently:

```
to fwd-reaction [ #asking-species species2 #x-k_on #x-alpha #species-to-die #new-breed ]
  

  ask #asking-species [
    if (any? other species2-here ) and random-float 1000 < (#x-k_on * 2 * #x-alpha)
      [
            ask one-of other #species-to-die -here
            [ die ]
            set breed #new-breed
            set-attributes2 0 2 self true false red

          ]
        ]
      
end
```

EDIT:

Thank you, grow3 worked superbly.

Question 2:

There is a slight complication with turtles with a special attribute, how do I pass that within the args? For example:

```
ask monomers1 with [ aggregated = false ]
```

instead of just

```
ask monomers1
```

as the first arg?

Question 3:

Also, how do I pass an argument of a breed that has to be hatched?

like so

```
hatch-<breed> 1
```

but the breed passed as an argument as #hatching-species

```
hatch-#hatching-species 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two options.  I don't think either of these are great, but if I were writing it, I'd choose `grow2`, as you usually don't want to use `runresult` on a string unless you really have to.

`grow1` uses [`runresult` on a string](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run) it creates from the breed name, making `frogs-here` or `mice-here`.  `grow2` turns the turtle's breed into a string so it can compare to the breed name in [a `with` clause](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with).  Both are using [`word` to make the string](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#word).

Edit to add:  The first two options assumed the breed you are passing is a string value.  If you're getting an actual breed value from another turtle, maybe by doing something like `[breed] of my-turtle` you could modify `grow2` to take in the breed and drop the `word` stuff.  I put that as `grow3`

```
breed [ mice mouse ]
breed [ frogs frog ]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  create-mice 100 [ fd 100 set color grey ]
  create-frogs 100 [ fd 100 set color green ]
  
  ask n-of 100 patches [ grow1 "mice" ]
  ask n-of 100 patches [ grow2 "frogs" ]
  let mice-breed [breed] of one-of mice
  ask n-of 100 patches [ grow3 mice-breed ]
end

to grow1 [breed-name]
  let breed-here (runresult (word breed-name "-here"))
  if any? breed-here [
    ask one-of breed-here [ 
      set size (size + 1) 
    ] 
  ]
end

to grow2 [breed-name]
  let breed-here turtles-here with [(word breed) = breed-name]
  if any? breed-here [
    ask one-of breed-here [
      set size (size + 1) 
    ]
  ]
end

to grow3 [breed-val]
  let breed-here turtles-here with [breed = breed-val]
  if any? breed-here [
    ask one-of breed-here [
      set size (size + 1) 
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: thank you, grow3 worked superbly. I have edited my original question to ask another one related to this.

There is a slight complication with turtles with a special attribute, how do I pass that within the args? For example:

ask monomers1 with [ aggregated = false ]

instead of just 

ask monomers1 


as the first arg?

Comment: @bigbiodata In general on StackOverflow you should always ask a new question instead of editing in an elaboration.